# Scala play controller function type

Tags: scala, testing, playframework-2.0

I am writing my tool for testing Play Framework controllers in DSL style, extending `PlaySpecification`, I need to pass controller method to the method of my framework class, but I am a bit rusty about types. I find in scaladoc that Action has  `(Request[A] => Result)`

**So I did:**

```
def controllerHasStatusCode(ctlrFunc:Request[A] => Result, expectedHttpCode: Int) = {
  val result = ctlrFunc(0)(FakeRequest())
  status(result) must equalTo(expectedHttpCode)
}
```

But I have compilation error, `not found: type A`. Can anyone experienced in playframework help me, to pass controllers method as argument to my function?

Finally client would do something like `controller signin mustHaveHttpCode OK`, but question is not about it.

**Note:** probably the similar framework existing, but I would enjoy writing my own, step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make the function itself generic:

```
def controllerHasStatusCode[A](ctlrFunc:Request[A] => Result, expectedHttpCode: Int) = {
  val result = ctlrFunc(0)(FakeRequest())
  status(result) must equalTo(expectedHttpCode)
}
```

`[A]` might need further type constraints.

Comment: I find the solution, I should pass `ctlrFunc: Action[AnyContent]`